# Css - add top property to each div, with top property multiply?

Tags: css

[image]

I have 10 div, and every one of them has position absolute, width: 100px and height 100px. In this case, we will see only one div, as rest of div overlaps each other.

So i wanted to ask, if i can in pure CSS, select those div, and add every one, top property which should look like:

```
fist div : top:0
second div: top:100px
third div: top:200px
```

And so on...
I tried with for example with this formula, but without success:

```
:nth-child(n+x);
```

Thanks.

Comment: With pure CSS, you would have manually write 10 rules. With pre-processors like Less/SASS, you could write a loop (but the no. of elements must be known at compilation time). If you want it to be 100% dynamic (with unknown no. of elements) then you should use JS (or any library of your choice).

Comment: It should be said that absolute positioning I'd a very poor option here. You could do this with a more flexible layout with very little effort.

Comment: and any suggestions ?

Comment: `position:relative`. It's the best suggestion. With that, all your divs will be `margin-top: 100px` and them reorganize automatically

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that..

e.g.

```
<div id="wrapper">
     <div class="first-div">
     <div class="second-div"> 
</div>

<style type="text/css">

/* for first div */
#wrapper > div:nth-child(1) {
    top: 0px;
}


</style>
```

using jQuery, you can set top dynamically.

e.g.

```
jQuery('#wrapper > div').each(function(index){
    jQuery(this).css('top', index * 100);
});
```

Comment: Hey ! Great ! But how can i calculate top, when divs have custom height ? For example, first has 200px and second 400px. In this case, breat betveen divs will not be equal...?Thanks.PS: Added image, to show what i mean - red line sholu be break.

Comment: To get div height dynamically, you can use 

jQuery('#wrapper > div').each(function(index){
     alert(jQuery(this).height());
});

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Alpesh Panchal approach and still have variable height divs, you can just store the total height in a variable:

http://jsfiddle.net/4u9jLm95/2/

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="first"> </div>
  <div class="second"> </div> 
  <div class="third"> </div>
  <div class="fourth"> </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper div {
  background-color: teal;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
}

.first {
  height: 100px;
}
.second {
  height: 200px;
}
.third {
  height: 50px;
}
.fourth {
  height: 150px;
}
```

JS:

```
var total = 0;
$('#wrapper > div').each(function(index){
    $(this).css('top', total);
    total +=  $(this).height() + 100;
});
```

However, as others said, using `position: absolute` might not be the best option here.